# Is it possible to assign a work item in TFS to different people?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

TFS (2008) has the great feature of work item tracking where I can easily see what people are doing all day long. Now I was wondering if I could assign a work item to different people or if they could write time on an item in a trackable way.

For example: We have two developers Mr. A and Ms. B. A did 4 hours of work and 50% of the work item "Create customer screen" until he gets ill. Than B has to finish the other 50% but I do not want to lose the progress of A because it could seem that A worked 4 hours less and B 4 hours too much.

Unfortunatly it seems that I can enter only one name in "assigned to" when I am using TFS 2008 and can not store the item if I try to seperate the names by comma or semicolon. Do you know if such a feature is included in TFS 2010?

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This is one of the few aspects that haven't changed from 2008 to 2010.

Thomas

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about assigning one item to multiple people but you could setup groups to which multiple people belonged. I'm not sure of your other requirements but this should solve this issue here. In essence Mr A and Mr B would both belong to a group called, say, 'Developers' to which the work item is assigned. Thus the full 8 hours is logged against a single entity.

Here is [an (old) article](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/marcelv/archive/2009/04/07/how-to-assign-a-work-item-to-a-group-and-actually-have-it-show-a-list-of-values.aspx) on how to do this elegantly. You may want to split up your groups to as specific a category name as possible (e.g. 'Core Developers', 'Javascript Developers')

Found [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2009/05/18/tfs-2010-work-item-tracking.aspx#9631723) that implies that they are aware of the need but have not implemented a resolution yet

Answer (score 0):

In TFS, if you assign a work item to someone else it will maintain that in the Work Item History, which is available for reports. TFS 2010, however, only tracks 3 fields: completed work (in hours usually), remaining work, and original estimate.  If A and B both update completed work, you should be able to separate that work out in reporting services.

Comment: Thank for this answer. I will try this after we moved to 2010. I did not marked as accepted because it does not answer the initial question but thank you for your help.

Comment: I am just trying to respond with something that answers what I think the spirit of your question is (understand the hours worked by multiple developers on the same task) rather than what your actual question is (how do I assign a work item to 2 developers).

Answer (score 0):

As @DarrellNorton said, all the information is recoded in the history of the work item, so you can retrieve the completed work values for each historical entry and correlate that to the assignee at that point in time. So the information you need is already in your database, if you can work out how to extract it. (The danger is that if someone leaves the completed-work field unchanged you might record the first dev's hours against the second dev as well - you'd ideally need to add a state transition rule in your work item templates that clears the field back to 0 whenever it was assigned to a new developer)

Another approach is to add your own fields to your TFS work items. It would be very easy to add (for example) fields "HoursDoneByMrA" and "HoursDoneByMrB" and expose these onto the work item form so that each developer could have independent statistics by which you could track the information you require. As long as your team size isn't huge, this would be quick/easy to achieve, and would also give you an instant summary on the work item itself of all developers who had touched the work item and their contributed hours, so you wouldn't even need to go as far as building a specialised report. (TFS PowerTools provides editors for the work item types that make adding and displaying this information much easier than hand-editing the XML templates. This approach would work in TFS 2005, 2008, 2010 - once you know how to use the power tools to do it, it would only take about a minute per developer to put this in place).